# what are options in DATA MODEL(drools and jBPM, persistance)

Tags: drools, business-process-management

I am new to drools,while creating the Data Model some options are there like **drools and jBPM**, **Persistence** and **Advanced** can anyone tell what are those or a link where i can find the meanings of these.
any comments are welcome. Thanks..

Comment: How are you creating your data model?

Comment: sorry for late reply, i am creating it through ui(Business-Central). Authoring -> ProjectAuthoring , New Item -> DataObject